# Reactjs : Invariant Violation when using input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a bit new to React and was trying out a simple experiment.

I wanted to have a `text-box` and a `search-button` in my initial render, and then when I click on the `search-button`, I wanted a completely different markup (`close-button` + `div/h1`)

So I store the value in a state variable and in render method I check that state and decide upon the markup.

Here's the JSFiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/rso3uk9f/

**While doing this, I was facing 2 problems**

1. While clicking on the search-button, re-render happens and the results page is shown but the search button is not disposed.
2. When I click on close button, I get errors like

> Danger: Discarding unexpected node: " ".
>
> ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`:
>   .0.1

Can somebody give some clean workaround ?

Some of the work-arounds, I tried

- If you substitute input element with text-area or div then everything
  works fine.
- Also If I add an empty div after the search-button, then the empty
  div is renderend on the results page and search-button is not displayed. But the JS errors still comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an error in your HTML markup.

Instead of:

```
<input type="text"> </input>
```

Write simply:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.